# Tracking down javascript error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I inherited an old classic asp VB program which I have edited under VS 2010.  There is rather long javascript function ("check(this)") that validates the user-entered data upon submit. But now when the user clicks "continue" I am getting the following error:

[image: screen print of submit and error]

How best to track down this error? I am running Windows 7.

Comment: 1) perhaps something else is also called check 2) does check actually return a value in all cases?

Comment: "Check" appears only as this function name or in comments or error messages.  I will check every section of the function to see if it is returning a value but it is quite lenghthy, and embedded in the asp page.

Comment: I found the problem. While debugging something else I had added an alert and forgotten one of those pesky semi-colons javascript is so fond of.  I removed the alert and everything works.  Thanks to all for responding.

Answer (score 0):

It is just saying that the `check` function was never defined.

Make sure (with some sort of DOM inspector) that the function on the page and not enclosed by any closures.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Check is defined and it pre-dates my inheritance of the program. What do you mean by "not enclosed by any closures"?